# How does this numpy arrays assignment work: target[done] = rewards[done] where 'done' is also a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I came across this code in a machine learning example and cannot figure what is going on. The following values are an abstraction of much more numerous values in the example.

```
target = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
target[0], target[1], target[2] = 10., 20., 30.

rewards = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
rewards[0], rewards[1], rewards[2] = 55., 65 , 75

done = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.uint8)
done[0], done[1], done[2] = 0, 0, 0

print('Target: ', target, '  Rewards: ', rewards, '  Done: ', done)

Target:  [10. 20. 30.]   Rewards:  [55. 65. 75.]   Done:  [0 0 0]
```

Then **target** is assigned...

```
target[done] = rewards[done]
print('Target: ', target, '  Rewards: ', rewards, '  Done: ', done)

Target:  [55. 20. 30.]   Rewards:  [55. 65. 75.]   Done:  [0 0 0]
```

Note the 1st element of **target** is now the 1st element of **rewards**. How did that happen?

If I now reset **target** and **rewards** to initial values and change done to say 0, 0, 1

```
target = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
target[0], target[1], target[2] = 10., 20., 30.

rewards = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
rewards[0], rewards[1], rewards[2] = 55., 65 , 75

done = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.uint8)
done[0], done[1], done[2] = 0, 0, 1

print('Target: ', target, '  Rewards: ', rewards, '  Done: ', done)

Target:  [10. 20. 30.]   Rewards:  [55. 65. 75.]   Done:  [0 0 1]
```

and then perform

```
target[done] = rewards[done]
print('Target: ', target, '  Rewards: ', rewards, '  Done: ', done)
```

I get the 1st 2 elements of **rewards** into **target**.

```
Target:  [55. 65. 30.]   Rewards:  [55. 65. 75.]   Done:  [0 0 1]
```

I have tried differrent combinations of 0s and 1s in done but cannot see any correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

When you index an array with an integer array, the result is a permutated view of the original array, if that makes any sense.

Let's say you have

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
B = [s, t, u, v]
I = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

then

```
A[I] = [a, a, a, b]
```

and

```
B[I] = [s, s, s, t]
```

so when you do A[I] = B[I], you copy s to a, and t to b.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ture. Google brought me to that documentation you referenced but I coud not relate it to my situation.